# How to render actions in ToolbarAndroid for React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using the "react-native-scrollable-tab-view" which is a great Android & iOS Tab Navigation. On top of the tabs i want to render the ToolbarAndroid actions which has it´s own options on each tab. For e.g. tab one has a toolbar with different action icons as tab two has. 
 How could i solve this?

**This is my ScrollableView:**

```
<ScrollableTabView
            renderTabBar={() => <CustomTabBar someProp={'here'} />}>
            <View style={styles.tabView} tabLabel="Page1">
                <Page1View/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.tabView} tabLabel="Page2">
                <Page2View/>
            </View>       
 </ScrollableTabView>
```

**And here is my CustomTabBar:**

```
var CustomTabBar = React.createClass({

  selectedTabIcons:   [],
  unselectedTabIcons: [],

  propTypes: {
    goToPage:  React.PropTypes.func,
    activeTab: React.PropTypes.number,
    tabs:      React.PropTypes.array
  },

  renderTabOption( name, page ) {
    var isTabActive = this.props.activeTab === page;

    return (
        <View style={[styles.tab]}>
            <Button key={name} onPress={() => this.props.goToPage(page)}>
                <Text
                    style={{color: !isTabActive ? '#6393B8' : 'white', fontWeight: isTabActive ? 'bold' : 'normal', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', fontFamily: VALUES.FONTS.FONT_REGULAR}}>
                    {name}
                </Text>
            </Button>
        </View>
    );
  },

  render() {
    var numberOfTabs      = this.props.tabs.length;
    var tabUnderlineStyle = {
        position:        'absolute',
        width:           deviceWidth / numberOfTabs,
        height:          4,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        bottom:          0,
    };

    var left = this.props.scrollValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [ 0, 1 ], outputRange: [ 0, deviceWidth / numberOfTabs ]
    });

    return (
        <View>
            <ToolbarAndroid
                title="TITLE"
                titleColor='white'
                style={styles.toolbar}
                actions={toolbarActions} ==> render this to be updated to actual tab with different Tab actions
            />
            <View style={styles.tabs}>
                {this.props.tabs.map(( tab, i ) => this.renderTabOption(tab, i))}
                <Animated.View style={[tabUnderlineStyle, {left}]}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  },
});
```

**Here is how my current toolbarActions are defined right now:**

```
var toolbarActions = [
    { title: 'Create', icon: require ('image!ic_create_black_48dp'), show: 'always' },
    { title: 'Filter' },
    { title: 'Settings', icon: require ('image!ic_settings_black_48dp'), show: 'always' }
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var toolbarActionsForPageOne = [
  { title: 'Option1' },
  { title: 'Option2' },
];

var toolbarActionsForPageTwo    = [
  { title: 'Something1', },
  { title: 'Something2', },
];
```

Then use the **activeTab property** to identify current tab, and write a function which takes this as parameter to return the needed options:

```
function toolbarActions ( currentTab ) {

  switch (currentTab) {
    case 0:
        return toolbarActionsPageOne
    case 1:
        return toolbarActionsPageTwo
    }
}
```

In your ToolbarAndroid View assign it to **actions**:

```
actions={toolbarActions(this.props.activeTab)}
```

Comment: This only seems to get called on the first page load. How would I trigger the toolbarActions function every time the prop is updated or a new scene is pushed?